# Coded UI Test Builder does not appear with setup project in solution

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, coded-ui-tests

I am using VS 2010, and I was able to create a Coded UI test successfully, once. I am trying to do the same, but the Test Builder Dialog box does not appear anymore. I found the following post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsautotest/thread/ff495f15-bb42-454d-88af-ae4d3bb4a075

This describes my problem somewhat. I do have a setup project, and when I remove the setup project and add a Coded UI Test, everything works. Then I add back the Setup project, and add a Coded UI Test, it works again.

Then I close VS 2010, re-open it, add a Coded UI Test, and the test buildor dialog bos does not show up.

Does anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2010 SP1 solves the issue of creating Coded UI tests in solutions having a setup project.

For a description of VS 2010 SP1 (with a download link) see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509. Search for the title "FastForward/CodedUITest" to find doc that this particular issue is solved.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, and or provide a link for the Service Pack or knowledge base page.